# Convert a postgresql query into something that works for mysql

Tags: mysql, regex, postgresql

Here is the PostgreSQL query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM rates 
WHERE prefix = (SELECT max(prefix) 
                FROM rates 
                where '914428215151' ~* ('^'||prefix));
```

MySQL craps out on `~*`

What is the equivalent for MySQL?

Comment: What does the where condition do?

Comment: @Mihai: `~*` is a regex operator in PostgreSQL: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL uses `RLIKE` or `REGEXP` as regular expression comparison operators.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp

PostgreSQL's `~*` operator is case-insensitive, and so is MySQL's:

> `REGEXP` is not case sensitive, except when used with binary strings.

The other difference is the usage of `||` as a string concatenation operator. You can make MySQL use that operator in the same way if you `SET SQL_MODE=PIPES_AS_CONCAT`, but by default it's a logical "or" operator, so you should use the `CONCAT()` function:

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM rates WHERE prefix = (
  SELECT MAX(prefix) FROM rates 
  WHERE '914428215151' REGEXP CONCAT('^', prefix));
```

---

Re your comment:

Don't use `||` as string concatenation.  Use the `CONCAT()` function.

If you use `||`, it is a logical "or".  The result of `('^' OR prefix)` is **true**, which is represented by the number 1 in MySQL.  The regexp comparison `'914428215151' REGEXP '1'` obviously matches any value, so it returns the MAX() value in the table.

Comment: Excellent, that works.  I do have one small problem that I do not understand however.  This query: SELECT * FROM rates WHERE prefix = (SELECT max(prefix) FROM rates where '914428215151' REGEXP ('^'||prefix)); returns a match from the queried column of 99899 however I see 91442 exists, so it definitely is not the closest match.  What have I missed?

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple LIKE for the where clause.

```
SELECT max(prefix) FROM rates where prefix LIKE '914428215151%'
```

Comment: Prefix '91442' is matched by the OP's query, but not by yours.